# Error while inserting item to std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, clion

I'm trying to simply insert a new item to a map with custom key and value types:

```
struct Address {
    bool operator<(const Address& a) const { return 1; }
};
struct Cell {};

std::map<Address, Cell> map;
map.insert(std::make_pair<Address, Cell>(Address(), Cell()));
```

G++ compiles just fine but my IDE (CLion) complains about the argument of the insert method (marks it as an error by red underline): **Parameter type mismatch: Class 'std::pair<Address, Cell>' is not compatible with class 'std::initializer_list<std::map<main::Address, main::Cell>>::value_types>'**.

Why am I getting this error? Is something wrong with my code? Or is it a bug in the IDE?

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks, you're right. I simplified the question.

Comment: Could you please 1) specify what compiler are you using? 2) Post the complete example 3) Try to reproduce is on godbolt? [The code is compiling](https://godbolt.org/g/EyA8T2) for every compiler I tried on godbolt

Comment: Or do you mean it underlines it with red? The parser they use may be incomplete, you should use only as a hint. The authority here is the actual compiler, not the IDE. Try to compile and see if it works.

Comment: @IlyaPopov Yes, the IDE underlines it with red, nothing more. Like I wrote, it compiles perfectly - I'm just asking whether there is some "hidden fault" in the code that compiler wouldn't mention (and IDE does) or it's some bug in CLion.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký It could be because the `value_type` of a map is `pari<const Key, Value>`.

Comment: @juanchopanza `pair`, not `pari`.

Comment: And -- **yes, it's an IDE bug**. That's perfectly valid C++ code.

Comment: Please do not use `std::make_pair` with explicitly specified template arguments. This function is intended to *deduce* its template arguments from its function arguments, like so: `std::make_pair(Address{}, Cell{})`. If you want to specify the types, just use `std::pair<Address, Cell>{}`. You can get weird issues especially with lvalues when you use `std::make_pair` this way.

Comment: Huh, this could happen if the copy-ctor of one of the types was `explicit` and the compiler your IDE is using for analysis (red lines) uses a different (older) version of the Standard library than the g++ you're actually compiling with...

Comment: Maps need a comparison function for a reason. Implementing a dummy function that always returns true won't work. You need to implement an actual comparison function that satisfies a strict ordering. Also, it's a good idea to implement binary operators like `<` as non-member functions to allow for implicit conversions on the left parameter.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) width a [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).
To fix the problem change:

```
std::map<Address, Cell> map;
```

to:

```
std::vector<std::pair<Address, Cell> > map;
```

and include the vector library

```
#include <vector>
```